Dividing polygon into almost even triangles via growth algorithm (Python)
I have this code thats taking in the vertices of a given polygon, calculating its area, dividing it by n. After that, it takes one point of the polygon and "draws" a triangle with 2 different connecting points. The triangle should be almost the area divided by n. Afterwards, it repeats this step until the whole polygon is filled. But it doesn't work for some reason, and i can't figure out why.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def polygon_area(vertices):
    """Calculates the area of a polygon using the Shoelace formula."""
    x_coords = [p[0] for p in vertices]
    y_coords = [p[1] for p in vertices]
    area = 0.5 * abs(sum(x_coords[i] * y_coords[(i + 1) % len(vertices)] - y_coords[i] * x_coords[(i + 1) % len(vertices)] for i in range(len(vertices))))
    return area

def triangle_area(p1, p2, p3):
    """Calculates the area of a triangle."""
    return 0.5 * abs(p1[0] * (p2[1] - p3[1]) + p2[0] * (p3[1] - p1[1]) + p3[0] * (p1[1] - p2[1]))

def grow_triangle_to_area(p1, p2, target_area, base_point):
    """Grows a triangle by moving a point on the edge until the target area is reached."""
    left = 0
    right = 1
    while right - left > 1e-6:  # Tolerance for accuracy
        mid = (left + right) / 2
        p_mid = (p1[0] * (1 - mid) + p2[0] * mid, p1[1] * (1 - mid) + p2[1] * mid)
        current_area = triangle_area(base_point, p1, p_mid)
        if current_area < target_area:
            left = mid
        else:
            right = mid
    return (p1[0] * (1 - left) + p2[0] * left, p1[1] * (1 - left) + p2[1] * left)

def subdivide_polygon_growth(vertices, n):
    """Divides the polygon by growth into n approximately equal areas."""
    total_area = polygon_area(vertices)
    target_area = total_area / n  # Target area for each small polygon
    polygons = []
    
    base_point = vertices[0]  # Fixed base point for all polygons
    current_index = 0

    # Divide the polygon into n-1 polygons
    while len(polygons) < n - 1 and current_index < len(vertices) - 1:
        v1 = vertices[current_index]
        v2 = vertices[current_index + 1]

        # Calculate the triangle
        current_area = triangle_area(base_point, v1, v2)

        if current_area < target_area:
            # The triangle fits within the target area
            polygons.append([base_point, v1, v2])
            current_index += 1  # Increment the index
        else:
            # Grow the triangle until it reaches the target area
            p_new = grow_triangle_to_area(v1, v2, target_area, base_point)
            polygons.append([base_point, v1, p_new])
    
    # The last polygon takes the remaining area
    remaining_polygon = [base_point] + [vertices[i] for i in range(current_index, len(vertices))] + [base_point]
    polygons.append(remaining_polygon)

    return polygons

def plot_polygons(polygons):
    """Graphically displays the subdivided polygons."""
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for poly in polygons:
        p = Polygon(poly, closed=True, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6)
        ax.add_patch(p)
    
    # Set axis limits according to the coordinates
    all_x = [point[0] for poly in polygons for point in poly]
    all_y = [point[1] for poly in polygons for point in poly]
    ax.set_xlim(min(all_x)-1, max(all_x)+1)
    ax.set_ylim(min(all_y)-1, max(all_y)+1)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# Example polygon: vertices of a polygon
vertices = [(0, -5), (9, 0), (4, 3), (0, 3)]

# Number of desired subdivisions
n = 3

# Subdivide the polygon
subdivided_polygons = subdivide_polygon_growth(vertices, n)

# Output the coordinates of the subdivided polygons
print("Coordinates of the subdivided polygons:")
for i, poly in enumerate(subdivided_polygons):
    print(f"Polygon {i+1}: {poly}")

# Show the subdivided polygons graphically
plot_polygons(subdivided_polygons)

These are the coordinates of the triangles it drew:
They arent correct, sometimes have the same points twice, and sometimes have 5 points at oce. I Just don't get why.
I expectet 3 Polygons, that all have almost the same area, and the coordinates to the given polygons
Polygon 1: [(0, -5), (0, -5), (9, 0)]
Polygon 2: [(0, -5), (9, 0), (6.307696342468262, 1.615382194519043)]
Polygon 3: [(0, -5), (9, 0), (4, 3), (0, 3), (0, -5)]


Looks like you have 3 issues:

Your first triangle is including your base_point twice: [0,-5], [0,-5] [9,0]. You should start your current_index at 1
You are not incrementing current_index in your else case
Your remaining polygon logic needs some additional thought... You will likely need to incorporate p_new in the vertices somehow.

